# Redirect dynamic URL with two parameters to a static URL, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have dynamic URL with two parameters (Dynamic values) which I want to rewrite and redirect to Static URL:

http://www.example.com/pagename.php?id=[some_number]&title=[some-title-seperated-by-hyphens]

above URL should be rewriten and redirected to below URL so that when either of the two URLs is entered in the browser address 
bar it should show the below URL. And I also want that even on hover on 1st URL hyperlink it should show the static URL 
on the bottom left of the browser:

http://www.example.com/[some_number]/[some-title-seperated-by-hyphens]

I have tried the below code and it does not work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/pagename\.php\?id=([^&]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(-[^/]+)/?$ /pagename.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pagename\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^(\S+)$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ pagename.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, I need the words of the title (second parameter) to be hyphen (-) separated.

Comment: Like the URL of this page of stackoverflow, the second parameter is the heading of the page but the URL has seperated the words by hyphens (dashes).

Comment: I enter (http://example.com/pagename.php?id=1&title=the%20heading%20of%20the%20page) and I want to get (http://example.com/1/the-heading-of-the-page) but your rule I get (http://example.com/1/the%2520heading%2520of%2520the%2520page).

Comment: Thanks a ton Anubhava, it worked, but we get Internal Server Error if the URL is too long.

Comment: If there are too many spaces to be replaced then use: `RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]`

Comment: this is works fine. But when I test on localhost it will redirect to localhost. Can you please help

Comment: That looks like an unrelated problem, Please post a new question and we'll help you.